# Random number generator and counter

Tags: java

I have to write a method that uses a loop to generate a random number between 1 and 10 (including 1 and 10) as many times as it takes to generate val 5 times and then print the number of times it took.
This is the code i have so far

```
int ranNum;
int counter;
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    ranNum=(Math.random() * (10));
    if(ranNum==val){
        counter= counter +1;
    }
}
System.out.println(counter);
```

But the 'as many times as it takes to generate val 5 time' part is confusing me. Could somebody please help me out?

Comment: you should keep 2 counters. One to count the number of tries and another to count the number of times val is generated

Comment: as Renuka is saying, you should nest all that code in another loop `for(int tries = 0 ; counter<5 ; tries++){ counter=0; /*your code*/} Sys.print(tries)`

Comment: Thank you Renuka and Maljam!

Comment: Basically, you have to keep track of how many times a number get generated, and when one of the numbers reaches 5 occurences, you are done. For example, you generate randomly `1,2,1,3,1,4,1,5,1`, in this sequence you have reached 5 '1' and it took 9 attempts to do this. (This means that your `for` is wrong, it can take more than 10 attempts)

Comment: You need to explain what `val` is and how it is initialized before we could even begin to answer this. But it does sound more like you're asking us to interpret your homework than correct a bug in your code. The only hint I can give you based on what you wrote is that the loop should absolutely NOT be a for loop. Note the fact that `i` isn't even used inside the loop body for anything. Craft an appropriate condition and use a while loop.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you first have to generate a random number between 1 and 10 inside a loop.  You count how many times it takes to obtain the value `val` with this random number.

1. Initialize a variable to count the numbers of trials (`int count=0;`).
2. You also need another variable to count how many times the random number is equal to `val` (example `int success=0;`).
3. `val` should be a number passed as an argument.
4. Since you cannot know how many times it will take, you would better use a `while` loop than a `for` loop.

Finally, your formula returns a floating point value, since `Math.random()` returns a value between `0.0` and `0.99999...`.  Therefore `Math.random() * 10` will be a floating point value from 0.0 to `9.999999`.  Just add one to get value from `1.0` to `10.9999...` that will be converted to an integer from 1 to 10 (not 0 to 9).

The variable `success` should be the result of your function.